# Android emulator Output

Tags: android

when i am trying to run my android application at that time
" `The application has stopped unexpactadly,Please try again`" and force to close application.
it comes every time.
can anyone try to solve this issue?
thanks

Comment: Did you remember to register your Activity in the manifest file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Dalvik debugger. Start the debugger from your commandpromt by typing: ddms

ddms is located within the tools folder where you installed the sdk. The debugger outputs all kind of info and errors.

Comment: Just for the reference I am going to add that ddms has been deprecated  in favor of the monitor command.

Answer (score 4):

Just run "`adb logcat`" or use the log viewer built into Eclipse and you should find a stack trace from the exception that caused the crash.

Answer (score 2):

Check the logs to see what exactly happened.

Either issue this command in the command-line interface

```
adb logcat
```

or check the log(cat)

Answer (score 1):

It is becaue some run time error happened in your application. Try to figure out the root cause by using log.